# trigger code getting error!

Tags: trigger

```
if(Trigger.isDelete)
{
    Map<string, Account> acdek = new Map<string, Account>();

    List<Account> ac = new List<Account>([select Name,phone from Account limit 20]);

    for(Account g : ac)
    {

        acdek.put(g.name,g);

    }

    List<Accountone__c> acde = new List<Accountone__c>([select id,Name,Phone__c from Accountone__c where Name in : acdek.KeySet()]);
    List<Accountone__c> bbb =  new List<Accountone__c>();

    for(Accountone__c ack :acde)
    {

        bbb.add(ack);

    }

    delete bbb;

}
```

The `acde` list is not getting populated. There are no errors, but the delete operation is not working properly.

Thanks,
Ganez

Comment: Save yourself some headache and use variable names that make sense.

Answer (score 4):

The object Accountone__c cannot have the same ID as the account. You are querying the wrong field here  "Id in : acdek.KeySet()"

Comment: I have edited my post pls check it

Comment: I am not sure this is correct but I don't know your schema, what's the name of the field that keeps the reference between the account and that custom object? You have updated your post with 'Name' but that would mean this is being stored in a text field, that doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

Using map is

```
Map<Id, Account> acdek = new Map<Id, Account>();
```

But quering from different object

```
 [select id , Name, Phone__c from Accountone__c where Id in : acdek.KeySet()]
```

i think map should be like

```
      Map<Id, Accountone__c> acdek = new Map<Id, Accountone__c>();
```

Comment: standard obj related custom object , if any thing ill do in standard obj (account) it  should be refeclted in custom object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using list ac use trigger.old

Answer (score 0):

i think no records are matching with the map , in this case list acde returns zero results, and before iterating for loop, check this list size is greater than 0, so we can optimize.

Comment: Since you're just querying for a random list of Accounts, do you really know for sure that there are Accountone__c records for all of them? It seems likely that your arbitrary Account list just doesn't have any Accountone__c records that match. Which means that `abcde` will have 0 Rows returned, and nothing will be deleted.